# How to inform users why their suggested edit where rejected?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

The problem I have is [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9052954). It sure is improving the answer but as it adds too much content on its own it should be considered a separate answer. It would feel wrong to *punish* the author by rejecting it without saying that it is indeed good content and worth a separate answer.

How do we solve these kind of review problems here?

Comment: Your rejection reason already explains that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I've never seen why my own edits were rejected. Where can I see that?

Comment: In your user profile --> Activity --> All Actions --> Suggestions.  Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303290/mbx?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).  For example, your most recent (not very recent) [rejected suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6233589).